# How to check if name already exists? Azure Ressource Manager Template

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-marketplace

is it possible to **check**, in an ARM Template, **if the name for my Virtual Machine already exists**?

I am developing a Solution Template for the Azure Marketplace. Maybe it is possible to set a paramter in the **UiDefinition** uniqe?

The goal is to reproduce this green Hook

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple notes...

- VM Names only need to be unique within a resourceGroup, not within the  subscription
- Solution Templates must be deployed to empty resourceGroups, so collisions with existing resources aren't possible
- For solution templates the preference is that you simply name the VMs for the user, rather than asking - use something that is appropriate for the workload (e.g. jumpbox) - not all solutions do this but we're trying to improve that experience

Given that it's not likely we'll ever build a control that checks for naming collisions on resources without globally unique constraints.

That help?

Answer (score 1):

This looks impossible, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/create-uidefinition-elements).

There are no validation scenarious.

Comment: is this not possible even in today's standards ?  I mean for any resource like functionApp etc

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you should be using the **Microsoft.Common.TextBox UI** element in your createUiDefinition.json.

I have tried to reproduce a green check by creating a simple createUiDefinition.json as below with a **Microsoft.Common.TextBox UI** element as shown below.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/0.1.2-preview/CreateUIDefinition.MultiVm.json",
  "handler": "Microsoft.Compute.MultiVm",
  "version": "0.1.2-preview",
  "parameters": {
    "basics": [
      {
        "name": "textBoxA",
        "type": "Microsoft.Common.TextBox",
        "label": "VM Name",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "toolTip": "Please enter a VM name",
        "constraints": {
            "required": true
        },
        "visible": true
      }
    ],
    "steps": [],
    "outputs": {}
  }
}
```

I am able to reproduce the green check beside the VM Name textbox as shown below:
[image]

However, **this green check DOES NOT imply the VM Name is Available.**
This is because based on my testing, even if I use an existing VM Name in the same subscription, it is still showing the green check.

Based on the official documented [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/microsoft-common-textbox#remarks) that are supported by the **Microsoft.Common.TextBox** UI element, it **DOES NOT VALIDATE Name Availability**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: he is asking specifically to validate..."if the name for my Virtual Machine already exists?"

Comment: Correct. I thought the green check is the same as validating the VM name.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I found out, so it is impossible to validate name availability now.

Answer (score 0):

While bmoore's point is correct that it's unlikely you would ever need this for a VM (nor is there an API for it), there are other compute resources that do have global naming requirements.

As of 2022 this concept **is** possible now with the use of the [ArmApiControl UI element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/microsoft-solutions-armapicontrol). It allows you to call ARM apis as part of validation in the createUiDefinition.json. Here is an example using the check name API for an Azure App service.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/0.1.2-preview/CreateUIDefinition.MultiVm.json#",
  "handler": "Microsoft.Azure.CreateUIDef",
  "version": "0.1.2-preview",
  "parameters": {
    "basics": [
      {}
    ],
    "steps": [
      {
        "name": "domain",
        "label": "Domain Names",
        "elements": [
          {
              "name": "domainInfo",
              "type": "Microsoft.Common.InfoBox",
              "visible": true,
              "options": {
                  "icon": "Info",
                  "text": "Pick the domain name that you want to use for your app."
              }
          },
          {
            "name": "appServiceAvailabilityApi",
            "type": "Microsoft.Solutions.ArmApiControl",
            "request": {
              "method": "POST",
              "path": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/checknameavailability?api-version=2021-02-01')]",
              "body": "[parse(concat('{\"name\":\"', concat('', steps('domain').domainName), '\", \"type\": \"Microsoft.Web/sites\"}'))]"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "domainName",
            "type": "Microsoft.Common.TextBox",
            "label": "Domain Name Word",
            "toolTip": "The name of your app service",
            "placeholder": "yourcompanyname",
            "constraints": {
              "validations": [
                {
                  "regex": "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,30}$",
                  "message": "Alphanumeric, between 4 and 30 characters."
                },
                {
                  "isValid": "[not(equals(steps('domain').appServiceAvailabilityApi.nameAvailable, false))]",
                  "message": "[concat('Error with the url: ', steps('domain').domainName, '. Reason: ', steps('domain').appServiceAvailabilityApi.reason)]"
                },
                {
                  "isValid": "[greater(length(steps('domain').domainName), 4)]",
                  "message": "The unique domain suffix should be longer than 4 characters."
                },
                {
                  "isValid": "[less(length(steps('domain').domainName), 30)]",
                  "message": "The unique domain suffix should be shorter than 30 characters."
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "section1",
            "type": "Microsoft.Common.Section",
            "label": "URLs to be created:",
            "elements": [
              {
                "name": "domainExamplePortal",
                "type": "Microsoft.Common.TextBlock",
                "visible": true,
                "options": {
                    "text": "[concat('https://', steps('domain').domainName, '.azurewebsites.net - The main app service URL')]"
                }
              }
            ],
            "visible": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "desiredDomainName": "[steps('domain').domainName]"
    }
  }
}
```

You can copy the above code and test it in the [createUiDefinition.json sandbox](https://portal.azure.com/?feature.customPortal=false#view/Microsoft_Azure_CreateUIDef/SandboxBlade) azure provides.